# AWS lambda function listen to prefix recursively when Object is created in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to build a Lambda in AWS which will be invocated when an object is created in bucket 'test' with prefix 'a/b/2017/05/08' for today's data. But tomorrow, it will be written to 'a/b/2017/05/09'.

I try to create the Lambda with prefix setting to 'a/b', but in this way, only when I create a file in 'a/b/tmp.txt' will the lambda be triggered. If I create in 'a/b/2017/05/09', then the lambda is not triggered anymore.

Could anyone help me out? How to make Lambda listen to creating files in all subdirectories? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you re-phrase it?

Comment: *"but in this way, only when I create a file in 'a/b/tmp.txt' will the lambda be triggered."*  That should not be the case, but the prefix you really want would probably be `a/b/` rather than `a/b`.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is not true.

Configuring an S3 trigger with an object-key prefix - **is recursive**.

See the following trigger definition:
[image]

This is the simple lambda that was triggered by this event:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let lastRecordObjectKey;
    event.Records.forEach(record => {
        lastRecordObjectKey = record.s3.object.key;
        console.log(lastRecordObjectKey);
    });

    callback(null, lastRecordObjectKey);
};
```

This is the CloudWatch logs, showing that for each of the recursive paths - the lambda was triggered.
[image]